# Proof of Rudin's Theorem 8.14, RCA

Tags: real-analysis, convolution

In Rudin's proof of Theorem 8.14, which states that convolutions of Lebesgue integrable functions over the real line are Lebesgue integrable, he first proves the result for Borel measurable functions, as opposed to the more general Lebesgue measurable functions. I fail to see why this is necessary -- the proof for the measurability of the product function

$$f(x-y)g(y)$$

over the plane can be shown without that assumption, I think; just note that compositions of measurable functions with continuous functions are measurable, and so are products of pairs of measurable functions. Am I missing something?

Comment: @AhmedHussein I don't understand why Borel measurability is assumed. edit: where did you go? lol

Comment: The "compositions of measurable functions with continuous functions are measurable" only works in the other order, if $h\colon X \to Y$ is measurable, and $k \colon Y \to Z$ is continuous, then $k \circ h$ is measurable (1.7. b). Here, you have a Lebesgue- resp. Borel-measurable $f$, and the continuous function $\delta \colon (x,y) \mapsto x-y$, and look at the composition $f \circ \delta$. Now if $f$ is Borel-measurable, then it's straightforward to see that $f \circ \delta$ is also Borel-measurable (1.12 d), since continuous functions are Borel measurable.

Comment: But it's not easy to show that $f \circ \delta$ is Lebesgue measurable if $f$ is only assumed to be Lebesgue measurable, for the inverse image of a Lebesgue null set under a continuous map may be non-measurable.

Comment: @DanielFischer oh i see. i didn't pay enough attention to the direction in 1.7b.

Comment: @DanielFischer People posting comments while I'm typing again...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say we should just note that "compositions of measurable functions with continuous functions are measurable". If we're applying that to $f(x-y)$ we must be talking about $f\circ\phi$ where $f$ is measurable and $\phi$ is continuous (as opposed to $\phi\circ f$). But in general $f$ measurable and $\phi$ continuous does *not* imply that $f\circ \phi$ is measurable! Of course here $f(x-y)$ *is* measurable, but not for the reason you say it is.

An explicit example of the phenomenon Daniel Fischer mentions:

Say $C\subset[0,1]$ is the middle-thirds Cantor set and $K\subset[0,1]$ is a "fat Cantor set": $K$ is homeomorphic to $C$ but $m(K)>0$. Assume $0,1\in K$. Then there is a homeomorphism $\phi:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ with $\phi(K)=C$.

Now since $m(K)>0$ there is a non-measurable set $E\subset K$. Let $F=\phi(E)$. Then $F$ is measurable since $F\subset C$ and $m(C)=0$. So $\chi_F$ is measurable, while $\chi_F\circ\phi=\chi_E$ is not measurable.